# Is it possible to run GDrive with Bourne Shell or Almquist shell (sh or ash) on xiaomi smart ip camera?

Tags: shell, software-installation, embedded, ash, google-drive

I have an IP camera with the armv5tejl processor. My aim is to send videos from camera to GoogleDrive. I downloaded gdrive but it can be run only with bash. Is it possible to run gdrive somehow without bash?

```
# uname -m
armv5tejl

#ls -l $SHELL
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Jul 11  2014 /bin/sh -> busybox

# ./gdrive-linux-arm about
Illegal instruction
```

**Answer:**
No it isn't possible. But I have written gdrive especially for xiaomi smart ip camera to send videos to google drive. It works good. 1 MB of free RAM is totally enough. You can take it here: https://github.com/porunov/xiaomi_gdrive

Comment: # echo $SHELL
/bin/sh

Comment: I have no /bin/bash

Comment: But you can not run it with sh. It shows: "gdrive-linux-386: 1: gdrive-linux-386: Syntax error: "(" unexpected"

Comment: What is the output of `file gdrive-linux-386` and `uname -m`? It's probably a binary file.

Comment: There’s not enough information here to answer your question. You should [edit] it to include details such as which Unix-like system you are running (`uname -a`), the details other commentators have mentioned, and which shell you’re using, `ls -l $SHELL` (presuming you’re not using a shell other than your login shell).

Comment: gdrive-linux-386: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped

Comment: uname -m: armv5tejl

Comment: Thank you for help. My fault. Next time I will add more information.

Comment: it's a really bad idea to put cameras like this on the internet.  there have been numerous articles over the years detailing their security flaws (including the fact that most of them have [backdoors](https://jumpespjump.blogspot.com.au/2015/09/how-i-hacked-my-ip-camera-and-found.html)  created by the manufacturer and/or their suppliers, and recent news about yet another [DDOS attack from IP camera botnets](http://thehackernews.com/2016/06/cctv-camera-hacking.html).  keep it safe behind a firewall, with a private RFC-1918 IP address.  More: https://www.google.com/search?q=ip+camera+back+door

Comment: Yes, and it's fun to exploit these resources: they do not usually log anything beyond next reboot :)

Comment: My camera behind the switch. All ports on the switch are blocked. My camera has 32MB RAM space and 4 MB free RAM space which is enough to run small script which will send small videos (3-4MB each) to the Google Drive via "wget". My camera alredy send these videos via ftp to the filesanywhere.com . But last week this site has died (They are moving to a new data center). So I decided to rewrite script to store videos in the Google Drive. I don't need GDrive already. I will use only wget. Thank you guys for the help and advice

Answer (score 4):

Your IP camera is embedded system. This means that it have so little resources available that it cannot even store "fat" bash binary on itself.

It's probably has too little RAM too to store it on memory or the operating system inside it is locked down so you will not be able to store bash binary permanently on it.

You need to find out how to receive streams from that device and send them (optionally with converting to save bandwidth) from your main computer or server.

More, you should check your binaries are compatible. You cannot just run i386 binary on arm machine unless there is some kind of emulator is there. `file` command is helpful there.

Comment: I have found streams, also I ran a script which uploads videos on a remote ftp server. But the problem is that I need somehow send these videos to the google drive. It's a pity that google drive doesn't have ftp access.

Comment: It's not clear _where you do not have_ bash installed. On the camera is most likely. On your computer - why don't you have bash?

Comment: I talk only about camera. Of Course I have the bash on my laptop.

Comment: So summary is: your `gdrive-linux-386` is i386 executable which will run on your laptop but will not run on your camera, because camera has arm cpu. And even if there was a `gdrive-linux-arm` it probably will not run correctly on camera, unless it's statically linked and has low memory requirements, which are both _very_ unlikely. So you still have to find out how to obtain a raw stream from camera and proxy it to google drive from laptop.

Comment: @siblynx actually the pre-compiled versions [*are* statically linked](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive) :) He just needs to get `gdrive-linux-arm`, like you said.

Comment: Good! Now to find out will they run there. I always thought that nearly social web 2.0 services require lots of RAM and powerful machines just to send data to them.

Comment: Hello siblynx, you were wrong about RAM. I have created my own version of GDrive and it works good .1MB of free RAM is totally enough for send videos through https to google drive. I have posted it here: https://github.com/porunov/xiaomi_gdrive